# DWG converter for Node.js or Javascript library

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, autocad, dwg

I want to show AutoCAD-files (.DWG)  in my AngularJS application and I'm using a Node.js backend for my application.

Are there any DWG libraries in Javascript? 
Are there any DWG Node libraries to convert DWG files to a SVG / PDF / ...

I don't want to edit them; just show them online in my application.

The only that i could find was this :
http://etc.nkadesign.com/Download/Cad2svg

It's a linux command-line utility but I cannot use it since I want to 
host my application on the Heroku platform.

Comment: @tdhulser, don't forget to accept the answer if it help you in the pursuit of the question. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the autocad the 2014 JavaScript API 
http://adndevblog.typepad.com/autocad/2013/04/getting-started-with-javascript-api-on-autocad-2014.html

Here is a YouTube video

http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=PZKKJwcke2k&desktop_uri=%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DPZKKJwcke2k

Comment: How exactly using JS extensibility model for AutoCad helps you create Node-js application that can manipulate read DWG files? You cannot install AutoCad on Heroku either so IMO this is not an answer of the question in hand.

Comment: @MiroslavNedyalkov, feel free to give a more concise answer. I don't work in the JS API for AutoCAD, nor do I work on Heroku. This was merely a starting point suggestion for the OP. Your comment is pointless and serves no productive purpose. Have a good day :)

Comment: Unfortunately after researching the topic I figured out that there isn't very good solution. The best I found was abandoned C library called LibDWG (http://libdwg.sourceforge.net/en/). To summarize: I wish I had better answer of this question :) Have a nice day, too!

Comment: There is a tiegha file converter made by the Open Design Alliance.  It is a CLI exe that can convert dwg to dxf.  https://www.opendesign.com/guestfiles/teigha_file_converter   .Then there are lots of dxf parsers.  I like this one https://github.com/gdsestimating/dxf-parser

Answer (score 2):

There is a tiegha file converter made by the Open Design Alliance. It is a CLI exe that can convert dwg to dxf. opendesign.com/guestfiles/teigha_file_converter .Then there are lots of dxf parsers. I like this one github.com/gdsestimating/dxf-parser

Answer (score 1):

There is a NodeJS wrapper library for the Vector Express conversion API you may be able to use:
https://github.com/smidyo/vectorexpress-nodejs

Comment: im interested in that library for a project, but unfortunately I was not able to understand the docs, there's any other way to check all what this lib can do?
im trying to find the way to render a pdf which was exported from autoCad